# How can I build .ipa file from Ionic3 using Windows machine?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ipa, ionic3

I have few questions. I am very very new to Ionic3 and Hybrid application development.

I have developed a Ionic3 Angular4 hybrid application. I am using Windows OS 10 64 bit. So I have built **.apk** file and I have done the testing in my android mobile. it works as expected. Now its the turn for IOS app.

**Question# 1:** How can I build IOS .ipa file?

**Question# 2:** Suppose if I have built .ipa  file (*as per the solution for my Question#1*),  is it possible to move the .ipa file to my Iphone and install as what I have done for Android?

**Question# 3:** Do I need a developer code/key for testing the app in my own Iphone device without downloading it from App Store?

**Question# 4:** What are all the things I need to do for deploying both .apk and .ipa file in the respective stores?

Comment: You cant create .ipa file on windows machine !

Comment: Did you get your answers?

Answer (score 8):

**Question# 1:** How can I build IOS .ipa file (using Windows machine)?

**Answer# 1:** **No** you can't, but **YOU CAN**. Use [ionic package](https://docs.ionic.io/services/package/).

> Ionic Packages makes it easy to build a native binary of your app in
>   the cloud. Perfect for developers using Windows that want to build iOS
>   apps.

**Question# 2:** Suppose if I have built .ipa file (as per the solution for my Question#1), is it possible to move the .ipa file to my Iphone and install as what I have done for Android?

**Answer# 2:** **Yes**, download IPA file and upload it ]on [diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) and open the generated link in safari, you will find install option there.

> Diawi is a tool for developers to deploy Development and In-house
>   applications directly to the devices.

**Question# 3:** Do I need a developer code/key for testing the app in my own Iphone device without downloading it from App Store?

**Answer# 3:** **Yes**, of course you need. And the UDID of your device must be there in your Provisioning Profile.

**Question# 4:** What are all the things I need to do for deploying both .apk and .ipa file in the respective stores?

**Answer# 4:** Team Ionic has already explained it in depth. Read [Chapter 6: Publishing your app](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html)

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's mandatory to build in a Mac to develop in iOS. You need Xcode and if you want to test you App in an iPhone you need to register that iPhone with Apple to the create the signatures that will allow you to run you App in that iPhone. You have a limited number of iPhone you can register in Apple.

An important difference between Android an iPhone is that in Android you create the certificates for production but there is not need to have one for testing. In iOS only Apple can create the certificates and you need them even for testing.

You may find a detailed manual deploying for Android and iOS here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/

Answer (score 0):

**Answer# 1**: You can build IPA using MAC machine, you need Xcode to build IPA.

**Answer# 2**: Yes you can install ipa  on your iphone. Use Diawi link. Upload your IPA on diawi and use that link to install IPA.

**Answer# 3**: Developer or Inhouse provesioning profile is must.

**Answer# 4**: You need signing (.jks) file for android to build signed apk which is uploaded on play store.
For IPA you need certificate installed on your MAC machine, provesioning profile to generate signed IPA.